# What could be a right datascience approach of doing fuzzy string matching in large amount of short text data?

Tags: clustering, bigdata

I have two lists to compare. `List 1` contains strings which represent the strings in `List2`. Sometimes, they are direct matches, some times, one word match, sometimes there are acronyms etc. An example is as below:

```
   List1           |  List2
  ------------------------
   great hall town | Great Hall
   grt_town        | Great Hall      
   gHall           | Great Hall
   great town      | Great Hall
   mind great town | Great Hall
```

There are two main problems:

1. `List2` is very large ( millions of records, all short in length)
2. `List1` records are very unrelated sometimes. There are longer prefixes, suffixes which are not in `List2`. Some words in `List2` are reduced to a letter.

I vaguely have some thoughts around clustering `List2` and trying to find distance between centroids and the elements from `List1`. Do you think this as a starting point?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What problem are you trying to solve?  You give us the background about some data you have but don't tell us what you're trying to accomplish, so it's not clear what your specific question is.  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Why do you think "great town" should match "great hall" and not, say, "great wall" or "great fall"?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. Take distinct records from List2
2. Clean List1 of any extraneous characters or symbols
3. Use a fuzzy logic package like Python's [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy). It has partial matching options.